# Digit difference sort

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, sorting

So I am trying to solve this task "Digit Difference Sort" on Codefights

> Given an array of integers, sort its elements by the difference of their largest and smallest digits. 
>   In the case of a tie, that with the larger index in the array should come first.
>
> Example
>
> For a = [152, 23, 7, 887, 243], the output should be digitDifferenceSort(a) = [7, 887, 23, 243, 152].
>
> Here are the differences of all the numbers:
>
> 152: difference = 5 - 1 = 4;
>
> 23: difference = 3 - 2 = 1;
>
> 7: difference = 7 - 7 = 0;
>
> 887: difference = 8 - 7 = 1;
>
> 243: difference = 4 - 2 = 2.
>
> 23 and 887 have the same difference, but 887 goes after 23 in a, so in the sorted array it comes first.

I have an issue with two numbers having the same difference. Here's what I wrote so far:

```
int[] digitDifferenceSort(int[] a) {
    return a.OrderBy(x => difference(x)).ToArray();
}

int difference(int x)
{
    int min = 9, max = 0;
    do
    {
        int tmp = x % 10;
        min = Math.Min(min, tmp);
        max = Math.Max(max, tmp);
    } while ((x /= 10) > 0);

    return max - min;
}
```

Didn't do much (for example the output is still `[7, 23, 887, 243, 152]` rather than `[7, 887, 23, 243, 152]`)

How do I make element with larger index come first in result? What should I use instead of OrderBy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't consider your `difference` method, i assume it works fine. 
To your question: you have to keep revered order of the array (that the items with the same difference arrive will be sorted reverse). To do it, you could just reverse you input array:  all items with not identical difference will be ordered correctly, and with the same differece will be ordered reversed:

```
int[] digitDifferenceSort(int[] a)
{
     return a.Reverse().OrderBy(x => difference(x)).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I wouldn't even think of it :)

Answer (score 1):

Following is my code for the above question digit difference sort. I am also getting output when running in Eclipse but when I paste the code on code signal it gives me a null pointer exception.

```
package NormalPrograms;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class DigitDifferenceSort {
//  For index wise sorting in descending order
    public static int[] sortingnumberindexwise(int[] a, ArrayList<Integer> index) {
        int k = 0;
        int[] res = new int[index.size()];
        int[] finalres = new int[index.size()];
        for (int i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            for (int j = 0; j < index.size(); j++) {
                if (a[i] == (int) index.get(j)) {
                    res[k] = i;
                    index.remove(j);
                    k++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        int g = 0;
        k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            finalres[g] = a[res[k]];
            g++;
            k++;
        }

        return finalres;
    }

    public static int[] finddigitDifferenceandSort(int[] p) {
        int[] finres = new int[p.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < finres.length; i++) {
            finres[i] = p[i];
        }
        // This finres array act as an temp array and reused to make final result array
        int digit = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> A = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> B = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            B.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
            int temp = 0;
            temp = p[i];
            while (p[i] > 0) {
                digit = p[i] % 10;
                p[i] /= 10;
                A.add(digit);
            }
            int b = Collections.max(A);
            int c = Collections.min(A);
            int diff = b - c;
            B.get(diff).add(temp);
            A.clear();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < B.size(); i++) {
            if (B.get(i).size() > 1) {
                ArrayList<Integer> C = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                for (int k = 0; k < B.get(i).size(); k++) {
                    C.add(B.get(i).get(k));
                }
                B.get(i).clear();
                for (int j : sortingnumberindexwise(finres, C)) {
                    B.get(i).add(j);
                }
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < B.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < B.get(i).size(); j++) {
                if (B.get(i).size() == 0)
                    continue;
                else {
                    finres[k] = B.get(i).get(j);
                    k++;
                }
            }
        }
        return finres;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = { 12, 21, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3 };
        for (int i : finddigitDifferenceandSort(a)) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change the method name according to the code signal.